# Looping through worksheets in active workbook not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with multiple worksheets (dynamic) and want to do some simple calculations on each sheet (VBA Beginner).  I can do the macro on each sheet 
individually but the loop will not work.  No error message, but only executes on one sheet.  Code is below. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub Counts()

Dim Last As Integer
Dim Have As Long
Dim Miss As Long
Dim Total As Long
Dim Value As Currency
Dim Cost As Currency
Dim TVal As Currency
Dim ws As Worksheet



For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

Last = Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Miss = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("A2:A" & Last))
Total = Last - 1
Have = Total - Miss

Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A2:A" & Last), "X",Range   ("G2:G" & Last))
TVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("G2:G" & Last))
Cost = TVal - Value

Range("J2").Value = "Have"
Range("J3").Value = "Missed"
Range("J4").Value = "Total Cards"
Range("J6").Value = "Value"
Range("J7").Value = "Cost to Complete"
Range("J8").Value = "Set Value"

Range("k2").Value = Have
Range("k3").Value = Miss
Range("k4").Value = Total
Range("k6").Value = Value
Range("k7").Value = Cost
Range("k8").Value = TVal

Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

By default `Range` refers to the active sheet, and looping through the sheets does not mean each of those sheets is automatically activated.  You should always try to specify exactly which sheet you are referring to.  The code below uses `ws.Range` wherever you used `Range`.  (And uses a `With ws` block so that `ws.Range` can be shortcutted to just `.Range`.)

```
Sub Counts()

Dim Last As Integer
Dim Have As Long
Dim Miss As Long
Dim Total As Long
Dim Value As Currency
Dim Cost As Currency
Dim TVal As Currency
Dim ws As Worksheet



For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    With ws
        'I modified the next line to not use "CurrentRegion" as I wasn't
        'sure whether "CurrentRegion" would be meaningful without first
        'selecting a cell.
        Last = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Miss = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Range("A2:A" & Last))
        Total = Last - 1
        Have = Total - Miss

        Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range("A2:A" & Last), "X",.Range("G2:G" & Last))
        TVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("G2:G" & Last))
        Cost = TVal - Value

        .Range("J2").Value = "Have"
        .Range("J3").Value = "Missed"
        .Range("J4").Value = "Total Cards"
        .Range("J6").Value = "Value"
        .Range("J7").Value = "Cost to Complete"
        .Range("J8").Value = "Set Value"

        .Range("k2").Value = Have
        .Range("k3").Value = Miss
        .Range("k4").Value = Total
        .Range("k6").Value = Value
        .Range("k7").Value = Cost
        .Range("k8").Value = TVal

    End With    
Next ws

End Sub
```